# F# distinctBy behavior

Tags: f#, identity

I don't understand behavior of distinctBy in this snippet:

```
let s  = [123; 231; 321]
let s1 = s |> Seq.map        (string >> Seq.sort)
let s2 = s |> Seq.distinctBy (string >> Seq.sort)
```

which produces:

```
s1 = seq [seq ['1'; '2'; '3']; seq ['1'; '2'; '3']; seq ['1'; '2'; '3']]
```

as expected, but:

```
s2 = seq [123; 231; 321]
```

where I expected only one element, because the 3 keys are identical. Which part I got wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# does not compare Sequences for equality see this example

```
(123 |> string |> Seq.sort) = (123 |> string |> Seq.sort)
val it : bool = false
```

I imagine this is to allow support for infinite sequences.

You can fix this by mapping to lists

```
let s  = [123; 231; 321] |> Seq.distinctBy (string >> Seq.sort >> Seq.toList);;
val s : seq<int>

> s;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [123]
```

Comment: It works, thank you. As I wrote in comment to @Guvante: I was misled by `seq ['1'; '2'; '3'] = seq ['1'; '2'; '3']` evaluating to `true`, which must be an exception to the rule.

Answer (score 2):

`Seq.sort` probably doesn't implement comparison logic. So the underlying implementation sees three distinct objects.

Similar if you did the following:

```
object.ReferenceEquals("1", 1.ToString());
```

Comment: It produced three identical `seq ['1'; '2'; '3']` objects in the first case: `s1`

Comment: @PaulJurczak: And in my example the identical string `"1"` is produced yet the result is `false`. Equality is a complex beast.

Comment: I was misled by `seq ['1'; '2'; '3'] = seq ['1'; '2'; '3']` evaluating to `true`, but prompted by your response, I found that `(123 |> string |> Seq.sort) = (231 |> string |> Seq.sort)` evaluates to `false`. Not simple, indeed.

Comment: @PaulJurczak: The reason that works is because `seq` given an array or list does nothing but an upcast, the underlying object is still the same object. Since the list type implements a useful `Equals` method, you get `true` when you would expect.